# Unity3D - Replay a non-looping Particle System

Tags: particle-system, unity-game-engine

I'm following the [Survive Shooter](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/survival-shooter/scoring-points?playlist=17144) Unity3D tutorial and have come across several inconsistencies between the Unite Day presentation and actual behavior in Unity 5.3, such as animation transition and other small issues I had to figure out to achieve the desired gameplay result and follow the tutorial.

One issue I'm unable to resolve is replaying a non-looping particle system. In the game hit particles are emitted whenever an enemy is shot, but when running the game these particles are emitted once and not upon following hits.

This is the particle system configuration:

[image]

The original code simply re-positions and re-plays the emission:

```
// Set the position of the particle system to where the hit was sustained.
hitParticles.transform.position = hitPoint;

// And play the particles.
hitParticles.Play();
```

I've tried resetting and clearing the system but that didn't work:

```
hitParticles.Clear();
hitParticles.time = 0;
hitParticles.Play();
```

How do I replay the particle emission?

thanks!

Comment: Try `ParticleSystem.Emit(...)`

Comment: @JerrySwitalski it's still only emitting on first run.

Comment: Scratch that, I was still calling ```Play()``` after  ```Emit()```. Just calling ```Emit()``` is emitting every time.

Comment: @JerrySwitalski It may be worth fleshing that out into a full answer, so the OP has something to accept.

Comment: @Serlite okay, I will create the answer then. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reply the `ParticleSystem` try to use `ParticleSystem.Emit(...)` with parameters that suits your animation like:

```
hitParticles.Emit(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Unity 5.3.1, then it sounds very much like a bug(http://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/particle-system-plays-only-once).

Comment: Thanks @RPGamer, at least I know it's bug, there have been other bugs popping up throughout following the tutorial but at least I know it's my code to blame with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to reset immediately Particle system and repeat it (For example Rifle barel explosion) I would recommend you this:

```
ShootParticles.Simulate( 0.0f, true, true );
ShootParticles.Play();
```